# i need to use usb4java with eclipse plugin app but when i used USB.Frag.Init(0x04D8, 0x003F, 0x00, 0x81, 0x01, 1);?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, usb4java

this exception occurred

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/usb4java/LibUsbException
    at nattable.NatTableView$USB_Listner.run(NatTableView.java:128)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.usb4java.LibUsbException cannot be found by diagnostictool_1.0.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

i included the library already and i can't find what's wrong

build.propeties

http://pastie.org/10746488

Manifest.mf

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbYuD.jpg

Comment: How did you 'include the library'? Show us your plugin 'build.properties', and 'MANIFEST.MF' files. What is the library name?

Comment: build.properties

source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               files/,\
               plugin.xml,\
               libs/
jars.extra.classpath = libs/super-csv-2.1.0.jar


the folder libs and MANIFEST.MF

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57126915/Capture.JPG

Comment: Edit your question and put the files in the question.

Comment: So what library contains `LibUsbException`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include **all** the jars that your plugin uses in your plugin and include them in the `Bundle-Classpath` in the `MANIFEST.MF` file and list them (or the directory containing them) in the `build.properties` file.

You have included a `super-csv-2.1.0.jar` in your plugin, but you have not included the usb4java jar.

Comment: i edited Bundle-Classpath and it worked, thanks alot